# How to make morre readable URIs using unique-id-plus-redundant-information (UPRI) using PHP with Laravel

Tags: rest, laravel-5, url-routing

I would like to know the best (and most consistent) way to add redundant bits to my restful uris so that they are more readable while remaining unchanging when some things such as username change.

I read of the concept at [this excellent blog post](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) and it is something like what stack overflow does `/users/3836923/inkalimeva` where the last segment of the URI is redundant and may change but makes the URI more readable and SEO friendly.

Currently I am using Laravel's `Route::resource()` but that creates routes with only the id segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#using-the-class) to create slugs for your users. That way the slug will change when they update their username. You can also simply call their username in the url method, though this will result in uglier urls.

This method still requires that you drop Route::resource() and write your routes explicitly.

Here is the code, tested and working:

**ROUTES.PHP** (don't mind the route details)

```
Route::get('route-name/{id}/{slugOrUsernameAsYouPlease}', [
    'as' => 'admin-confirm-detach-admin',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@confirmDetachAdmin'
]);
```

**IN YOUR VIEW**

```
<a href="{{ url('route-name/'. $user->id . '/' . $user->name) }}">Click me!</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="{{ url('route-name/'. $user->id . '/' . $user->slug) }}">Click me!</a>
```

**URL RESULT** (My users name here is Fnup. Just for testing)

With Username: `http://website.local/route-name/8/Fnup`

With Slug: `http://website.local/route-name/8/fnup`

**A quick final note**

I just changed fnup's username to fnupper and here is the result:

```
http://website.local/route-name/8/Fnupper
```

However the slug didn't change automatically. You have to add that code yourself to the user update method. Otherwise the slug stays as what it was the first time the resource was made. Here is my code when using eloquent-sluggable

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->resluggify();
    $user->save();

    session()->flash('message', 'Din profil er opdateret!');
    return redirect()->route('user-show');
}
```

Which result in: `http://website.local/route-name/8/fnupper`

**New edit per request: Controller method example**

Here is my `confirmDetachAdmin()` method in `AdminController.php`. Just to clarify, the methods job is to show a "confirm" view before modifying a users status. Just like edit/update & create/store, I made up confirm to accompany destroy (since I'd like a javascript free confirmation option should javascript be disabled).

```
    public function confirmAttachAdmin($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        /* Prevent error if user already has role */
        if ( $user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return view('admin.confirmAttachAdmin', compact('user')); 
    }
```

You can add your slug/username as a second parameter if you want to, but I don't see a reason, as you can access it from $user when you find them by id.

Comment: Thanks but what I want is how to have both a userID and a username in the URL. The userID will be used for fetching the right user and it is unique and never changes whereas the username can change. Same thing for productID and productName

Comment: Updated the answer :) Same process with any kind of resource

Comment: Yes this is it, but can you show the controller code?

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to @MartinJH's answer, I don't think you should store your slugs in database if you don't rely *only* on them in your URIs. A simple `link()` method on your model, and an explicit route is enough.

**App\User**

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function link()
    {
        return route('user-profile', [ $this->id, Str::slug($this->username) ]);
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('{id}/{username}', [ 'as' => 'user-profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@profile' ])
    ->where('id', '\d+')
    ->where('username', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+');
```

**App\Http\Controllers\UserController**

```
...

public function profile($id, $username)
{
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail($id);

    return view('profile')->with('user', $user);
}

...
```

Comment: Please explain why you are returning a route from the model, I have not seen that pattern before. Also I can see you are using regex in your route declaration, does this make the routes "intelligent"? If I enter a String in the place for id, will that cause a 404 or something?

Comment: Not exactly a pattern. Building profile's URL in the model would save you from repeating that code in views. And yes, you are right about regex, I'm explicitly defining that I want 'id' to be numeric and 'username' to contain only alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores.

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend any good tutorial or book on Laravel 5 routing?

Comment: Jeffrey Way's tutorials on Laracasts are pretty awesome. Other than that I prefer reading through the source code than reading a book.